# How to solve this equation with quadratic equation in exponent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

How do I calculate $\left(\left(1-p\right)\left(x+1\right)\right)^{\left(x+1\right)\left(u-x\right)}-c=0$ to get a general solution for x? Other letters mean parameters.

Comment: I believe, there is no closed-form general solution. More simple $x^x=c$ does not have closed-form general solution.

Comment: What about their signs and size ? In any manner, this is a numerical problem. Can you give me a triple $(p,u,c)$ of your choice ?

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu $x^x=c$ is considered to have a closed form solution in terms of the Lambert W function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici just choose any x, u and p and you'll get the c satisfying the equation. But what I am trying to get is a general solution

Comment: I believe Lambert W function is out of closed-form definition. If you can use some special function, why not define solution of this equation as special function $f(p,c,u)$.

Comment: @IgorArciszewski: Why do you need a general solution? What do you plan to use it for?